# How to connect 2 thermostats and baseboard heaters on one breaker?

Tags: thermostat

I have already run the wire from the electrical box ( not connected) to the thermostats and heaters (not connected) now I need to know which wire is to be connected in order. It’s 12/2 gauge red and black. Thanks.  [image][image][image]

Comment: We will need more information to help are the heaters 120v or 240v, what is the wattage of the heaters and last what kind of thermostat single pole , double pole , bimetallic or electronic . All the above information will make a difference on how to connect everything.

Comment: red and black like you're in the Philippines or Japan?  North American /2 cable is normally Black-White-ground.   Do you have /3 cable that is Black-White-Red-ground?

Comment: In Canada, red 12/2 gauge wire 240v with red, black and ground wire. One heater 750w and 1500w. Thermostats are digital and programmable.

Comment: As Ed Beal asked, are the thermostats single pole or double pole? That is, do they have 2 connection points, or 4 connection points?

Comment: The thermostats are single pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first junction box with the first thermostat, connect with wire nut black wire from panel, black wire to next junction box, short pigtail wire to thermostat. Connect with another wire nut red wire from panel, red wire to next junction box, red wire to first heater. Connect black wire to heater to other connection on thermostat. Connect ground wire from panel to junction box then to wire nut, with ground wire to second junction box and to heater.

In the second junction box with the second thermostat, connect black wire from first junction box to thermostat. Connect red wire from first junction box to red wire to second heater. Connect black wire to heater to other connection on thermostat.  Connect ground wire from first junction box to second junction box then to wire nut with ground wire to second heater.

Comment: Thank you Ed Beal, Harper and kgc for your help. Now I’m more confident and ready for this diy challenge. Kgc thanks for your detail description A+.

Comment: The work is done and everything is working great. Can I another heater ( convection 1000w with thermostat integrated) to one of the heaters? How do I connect the wires? Thanks.

Comment: If your circuit breaker is 20 amp, and the 750 watt and 1500 watt heaters are all that are on this circuit, then an additional 1000 watt heater is OK - you should be good to about 4800 watts. Because each of the heaters are thermostatically controlled, you can directly connect an additional heater to the current heaters only if you are OK with the additional heater going on only if the first heater is already on. The thermostat in the additional heater could then control the it, but only within that range.

Comment: The new heater should probably be connected at one of the thermostats. In the 1st junction box, the wires would be connected at the wire nuts, black with other black, red with other red. At the 2nd junction box, connect with wire nut black from 1st junction box, black to 3rd heater, pigtail to thermostat, and connect with wire nut red from 1st junction box, red to 2nd heater and red to 3rd heater. And ground wires with 3rd wire nut.

Comment: Kgc thanks a million. I appreciate your knowledge.